# Firefox form targeting an iframe is opening new tab

Tags: html, forms, firefox

```
<form method="post" target="take_the_reload">

    ...

</form>


<iframe class="hide_me" name="take_the_reload"></iframe>
```

My issue is as follows:

I have a form that needs to be prevented from refreshing the page it is located on when it is submitted. To combat this issue, I have been using an empty `iframe` as the `target` for the form. This works exactly as expected in Chrome (v12.0.742) but fails in Firefox (v6.0).

What happens in Firefox, is that the iframe is opened in a new tab upon form submission, which is obviously not what I want.

I have found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701541/form-submit-to-target-iframe-only-works-once) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309782/targetting-iframe-with-form-causes-new-window-to-open) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495519/submitting-a-form-with-an-iframe-target), but none address my particular situation and their solutions do not work.

Unfortunately, the work is on a proprietary system in a private network so I can not just simply provide a link.

I have also tried using a `frame` as opposed to an `iframe` as an answer to a related topic was that using `iframe`s in such a manner is deprecated. But the results are identical.

Also the `iframe` is hard-coded into the page in the sense that it is not dynamically added with JavaScript. Finally, like I said earlier, this works flawlessly in Chrome, but fails to work at all in Firefox. IE is not a concern and so any non-IE-friendly solutions are welcome!

Comment: I had the same issue, the solution proposed in the accepted answer already applied, because my controller was return HTTP-201 without content. So I wasn't setting the content type neither. Just setting the content type solved the issue.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This might sound stupid but did you try giving the iframe an id the same as the name attribute? This seems to solve some problems relating to forms.

```
<form method="post" action="link/to/post/to" target="take_the_reload">

    ...

</form>

<iframe id="take_the_reload" name="take_the_reload"></iframe>
```

Comment: This was the solution. I hate missing small silly things like this. Thanks!

Comment: Firefox is so stupid for this in comparison with Chrome when the same piece of code worked perfectly in Chrome and buggy in Firefox.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Chrome today. I tried ur solution  which is giving the iframe id same as the name of the iframe (same as form target) and also in lowercase as suggested in another answer below. It works fine now in Firefox but opens a new tab in Chrome. Can anyone say why?

Comment: @HasanK That issue might be specific to you. Just in case, test it with only the form code in a very basic html layout (only head, body tags) and see what the behaviour is. If you get the same results you should make it a separate question and post your html code with it.

Comment: Reference this question if you specifically ruled it out as a possibility. Also, try out the answer below this one ;)

Answer (score 12):

TIP: Don't use capital letters in id and name

Doesn't work

```
<iframe id="formSubmit" name="formSubmit">
```

Works

```
<iframe id="form_submit" name="form_submit">
```

That was such a surprise for me!

Comment: Awesome! Still a valid fix in 2016!

Comment: What on earth is the cause for this? I can't find anything relevant in MDN.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone in the future looking into this, note that if you have two or more forms that target the same iframe id, **Firefox will open a new tab unless the two forms have different names.** Strangely enough, this isn't an issue in Chrome. So, for example, this won't work in Firefox

```
<form method="post" action="link/to/post/to" target="theiframe">
<!---input stuff here---->
</form>

<form method="post" action="link/to/post/to" target="theiframe">
<!---input stuff here---->
</form>

<iframe id="theiframe" name="theiframe"></iframe>
```

but it will work in Chrome. If you want the code to work in both Chrome and Firefox you'd have to do something like:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="link/to/post/to" target="theiframe">
<!---input stuff here---->
</form>

<form name="form2" method="post" action="link/to/post/to" target="theiframe">
<!---input stuff here---->
</form>

<iframe id="theiframe" name="theiframe"></iframe>
```

Don't know if this is a bug or Firefox is just designed that way. I'm working with Firefox 18 (latest version as of the time of this writing) and it's still a problem.

Hope this helps someone else; I was gnashing my teeth over this for about 2 hours before I finally figured out what the problem was.

Cheers!

Comment: It is ok to post a possible answer on ANY question no matter how old it is, as long as it is still relevant and useful information. What you added here definitely has value to people who encounter the problem given in the question, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

For those who may come across this problem later on, I solved it by adding a name attribute to to the iframe that was the same as the id of the iframe:

```
<iframe id='iframeID' name='iframeID'></iframe>
```

Stupid, yes, but that's the firefox likes it

Answer (score 1):

It may sound stupid and strange, but next steps solved my problem 
(Firefox opened new tab when submiting in Iframe)

1) Use the same value for "id" and "name" Iframe attributes

2) Do not use upper case in "id" or "name" attribute of Iframe (myIframe => my_iframe)

3) Check Iframe "src" attribute, it did not work for me when it was "about: blank", this attribute should be removed as I see

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add, none of the above worked for me. I found an additional reason that made it work.  Adding the id was done, and then actually adding a src= to the frame that's the same as the page it's going to show along with a ?.  So my code is:

```
    <iframe id="eframe" name="eframe" src="created.php?"></iframe>
```

Which resolves the issue, no longer opens in another window in firefox!

Comment: Please provide the reason why your answer works, so other can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of this problem: I was having this same problem, and the "name" / "id" suggestions were not making any difference.  I found that for me it seems to be a domain-related issue.

I open a page at http://mypc/app/page.aspx, with two iframes (A and B).

iframe A opens a new browser window to http://localhost/app/otherpage.aspx. 
otherpage.aspx has a form that targets iFrame B. 
Submitting the form opens a new window instead.

If I change iFrame A to open the new browser window to http://mypc/app/otherpage.aspx, then submitting the form from otherpage.aspx correctly displays the result in iFrame B.

So, at least in Firefox 47.0, it seems to be preventing cross-domain "targetting".  IE11 doesn't seem to have any such concerns (at least, between localhost and the actual machine name).