# Firefox opens links targeted for iFrame in browser's new tab instead

Tags: firefox, iframe, tabs, new-operator

I've found similar issues like this, but they are addressed to other specific situations. Haven't found an answer to mine so please help me out.

I've just set up a design for a Facebook Page. It has two buttons targeted to an iFrame. the thing is that when I clic on these buttons using Firefox, the link will open in a new tab instead of the iFrame targeted.

I've followed several instructions over the net and they doesn't work.

Here is the code (I don't understand instructions to make blocks, sorry, not a web developer):

```
<iframe id="models" width="460" height="545" src="images/navidadm1.jpg"></iframe>
```

The links are:

```
<img src="images/navidad_09.jpg" width="50" height="25" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.grupogorila.com/fbpage/milagrosdeamaranto/navidadm1.html" target="models">

<img src="images/navidad_12.jpg" width="50" height="25" alt=""></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.grupogorila.com/fbpage/milagrosdeamaranto/navidadm2.html" target="modelos">
```

... I hope I've showed the code correctly. If not, here is the actual page, in my server. I would really appreciate step-by-step answers since I am not a programmer :( (if adding javascript, exactly which line and between which lines).

http://grupogorila.com/fbpage/milagrosdeamaranto/
(the buttons are "Ver Modelos 1 a 4" and "Ver Modelos 5 a 8" in the lower part below the baskets)

Thank you, very, very, very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox form targetting an iframe is opening new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab)

Answer (score 9):

Give your iframe a name-attribute and an id-attribute, both the same value.

Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Try to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) instead of w3schools. See also http://w3fools.com/ .

Comment: This works, and it's not that surprising that different browsers connect the <form> target attribute to either the <iframe> id attribute *or* the <iframe> name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use JavaScript:

JavaScript code (in the head tags):

```
<script>
    function navigate(url)
    {
        window.frames['models'].location = url;
    }
</script>
```

Code for the links:

```
<a href="#" target="models" onclick="navigate("http://www.grupogorila.com/fbpage/milagrosdeamaranto/navidadm1.html");">

<a href="#" target="models" onclick="navigate("http://www.grupogorila.com/fbpage/milagrosdeamaranto/navidadm2.html");">
```

This is not tested, but should work! :)