# iframe: Subsequent clicks loads the new url in a new tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

!! SOS !!

**Problem Background:** I have a file which contains some page titles and corresponding URLs. I am reading this file dynamically and generating a table with each row showing the (clickable) title. There is one iframe on the page. I want that when a user clicks on one of the rows, the corresponding page should get loaded in the iframe. These urls may belong to different domains.

**Main Issue:** The first click opens the corresponding url perfectly in the iframe. However, any subsequent clicks (on the same or different row), opens the url in a new window, instead of replacing the earlier url in the iframe.

Tried googling it for long, but it appears that this problem is still unresolved (lots of empty posts without replies :-()

Please reply to this post. I will be happy to provide you with much more information/code if required.

Regards
P

PS: By the way, the same thing is happening with this simpler html code. Just two links and one iframe. Copy-paste this html file and try. One link will load the content in iframe and the other will redirect to a new tab :x :x

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><td><a style="text-decoration:none; line-height: 150%; color:darkslategray;" href="http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/markets/2013/01/04/stocks-higher-bull-market-high/1810075/" target="main_frame">GM, Peugeot to Decide on Brazil Factory This Month, Veja Says <br>Bloomberg News &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2012-05-19</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a style="text-decoration:none; line-height: 150%; color:darkslategray;" href="http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/01/04/us-markets-stocks-idUSBRE8BG0D620130104" target="main_frame">GM, Peugeot no Decide on Brazil Factory This Month, Veja Says <br>Bloomberg News &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2012-05-20</a></td></tr>
</table>

<iframe name="main_frame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" height="100%" width="100%" src=""></iframe>

</html>
```

Tested on both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it !!!

Used these two links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe
and [Firefox opens links targeted for iFrame in browser's new tab instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302247/firefox-opens-links-targeted-for-iframe-in-browsers-new-tab-instead)

and the following piece of code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function navigate(url)
{
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName( "iframe" )[0];
    iframe.src = url;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:navigate('http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/markets/2013/01/04/stocks-higher-bull-market-high/1810075/')">Some title</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:navigate('http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/01/04/us-markets-stocks-idUSBRE8BG0D620130104')">Some Other title</a></td></tr>
</table>

<iframe name="main_frame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" height="100%" width="100%" src=""></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of those web pages changes the `window.name` of its window, and targeting happens via window name, not frame name...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions, how can I fix that ??

Comment: Also, if one the webpages changes the window.name, how come when I click on the link for the first time, it opens in the iframe?

Comment: The first time you click the link, the web page that changes the name hasn't loaded yet.  As for how to fix... I'm not actually sure.  There are various hacks you could do in terms of scripted location sets, which are probably the simplest thing here.  It really depends on what your other constraints are.