# Hyperlink not opening in Iframe, instead opens in new tab

Tags: html, iframe

I have some hyperlinks on a left panel sidebar. On clicking any of them, the respective page should open in an iframe present on the right. Now, this is working fine for most of the links. But for some links and unfortunately, the links i need to use, it opens correctly in the iframe only for the first time of page load. After that, it keeps opening in a new tab.

The console says "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL1 from frame with URL2. Domains, protocols and ports don't match." **But this appears even in the cases when the links open up correctly in the iframe.** I am completely puzzled as to why this is happening. Help me out.

```
<a href= "some url" target="iframe_P"> </a>

<iframe src="random url" name="iframe_P" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

**Also I have tried using id = "iframe_P"**. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Are your links to your own domain or to a third-party domain?

Comment: The links belong to the same network that I am using. Since I am getting the "Domains, protocols and ports don't match" message on my console, maybe domains don't match. But for some other links which are definitely outside my domain, for example, for some public links, they open up in the iframe perfectly along with "Domains, protocols and ports don't match" message.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this:

```
 <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/" target="myIframe">Link Text</a>
    <iframe src="" name = "myIframe"></iframe>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HnXFj/45/)

Comment: Tried changing the url to yahoo.com and google.com; and didn't work. In short, this work on certain urls, not all.

Comment: I am doing it in the same way, as I have shown in my question. Doesn't work.

Comment: @aliasm2k yeah, my thoughts exactly. Any reason why this incosnsistent behavior?

Comment: My possible guess is that both yahoo.com and google.com have internal redirects which prevents it form being loaded in an iframe. I am no expert, this is just a hunch

Comment: Yeah, could be a case of internal rewrite.

Comment: Google and yahoo doesnt support this behavior. The reason for this is, that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170807/iframe-subsequent-clicks-loads-the-new-url-in-a-new-tab?rq=1 The last answer solved my problem. I thought I had searched stackoverflow extensively. Turns out I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe consider opening up the iframe in a modal pop up box. you can create a simple one which is fine for what you need here is an article about it:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

here is a jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkra4/1/
html:
    Open Modal

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h1>Delete this and put your iframe here</h1>
</div>
```

css:

```
   .modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
```

hope this helps