# Form targeting iframe not working in FireFox

Tags: php, html, firefox

I have a form that targets a hidden iframe.  This is working fine for IE, but nothing happens when the form is submitted in FireFox.  The is not being submitted.  Any idea what is causing the difference?

The form and iframe are here:

```
<form name="dial" method="get" target="callout" action="/cgi-bin/make_call.php">    
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" style="width:190px;" id="calling" name="calling" />
    <input type="hidden" name="caller" value="<? echo $extension; ?>">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-info btn-large" style="width:65px; height: 30px; position:relative;top:-5px;left:-2px; padding:0.2em; " value="Dial" />
</form>
<iframe name="callout" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

The page being loaded is:

```
<?
$caller = $_GET['caller'];
$calling = $_GET['calling'];

//Clean the non numbers out of our string
$calling = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$calling);

//If we are dialing a 7 digit number add a 9 to access an outside line
if(strlen($calling) == 7){
    $calling = "9".$calling;
    }

//If we are dialing a 10 digit number add 9 and 1 to access outside line
if(strlen($calling) == 10){
    $calling = "91".$calling;
    }

//If we are dialing a 11 digit number add 9 to access outside line
if(strlen($calling) == 10){
    $calling = "9".$calling;
    }

header("Location: http://XX.X.XX.XX:8070/ShoreTelWebSDK/REST/DialNumber?callingExtension=$caller&destinationNumber=$calling");  
?>
```

If I change the script to output a test message and target a visible iframe i still get nothing in FireFox, but again it works perfect in Internet Explorer.  Any idea what is causing the difference?

Comment: Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: Is your doctype defined as HTML 5? ("<!DOCTYPE html>")? "target" was deprecated in HTML 4.01. Also, your third "if" will never be executed (but that has nothing to do with the question)

Comment: @Digifaktur: _“"target" was deprecated in HTML 4.01”_ –  only in Strict, it was still allowed in Transitional. And using an iframe required Transitional to begin with, iframe was not allowed in Strict either. Besides, browsers usually tend not to care much about what is “officially” deprecated or removed, and value backwards compability much higher. So that a wrong doctype was/is the problem here is rather doubtful IMHO.

Comment: Works fine for me (FF 35 @ W7). What version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be facing the issue reported here: [Firefox form targetting an iframe is opening new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab) tl;dr: try adding an "id" attribute to the iframe, with the same value as the "name" attribute, and see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try add "@" to iframe name/target.

```
<iframe name="@callout"></iframe>
<form target="@callout"></form>
```

It helps identifier to recognize the name. The names need to specific and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the solutions worked for me. Luckily, I stumbled upon [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/secure-connection-failed-firefox-did-not-connect). It mentions "specific security products that can produce these errors, such as Avast, AVG and ESET software.". In my case it actually was the ESET Nod32 product that caused the error. When I disabled Web Access Protection (Setup -> Internet protection -> Web Access Protection) the problem disappeared. Have no idea why this problem occurs only with Firefox + ESET Nod32 combination.