# Chrome opens report in new tab, while firefox opens it in iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, reporting-services, target

Im trying to open a report from `SSRS` in an `iframe`. I've got a `form`, where I call a URL with `POST` and send some parameters from hidden inputs. I also have a `target` on my `form`, which contains the `id` of the `iframe`, hoping to display my report in my `iframe` on the same site. This works fine on `firefox`, my report is displayed in the `iframe`. The problem I have is the `chrome`. It also opens the report correctly, but in a new tab and not in my `iframe`. I searched a lot, didn't get an answer. Also this didn't help: [Firefox form targetting an iframe is opening new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab)

You can run my html on `chrome` and `firefox`. In firefox it will display you the error in the `iframe`, in chrome it will open a new tab and display the error there. The same thing happens, when I load my report from `SSRS`. I also attached screenshots to show you the difference. Any ideas?:

```
<form id="render" action="http://myReportUrl" method="post" target="display_in_iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render">
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:Toolbar" value="False">
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="display_in_iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="Dossier" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="DatumVon" value="2017-01-01">
    <input type="hidden" name="DatumBis" value="2017-07-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Report">
</form>

<iframe id="display_in_iframe" name="display_in_iframe"></iframe>
```

Report in `chrome` -> opens new tab:

[image]

Report in `firefox` -> stays on same site and opens report in `iframe`:

[image]

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem, works fine in my chrome. Check your chrome plugin's, maybe you have something like "click to tab" installed that causes this behaviour

Comment: @niktrs Strange... I tried it on 3 different machines, I still got this problem? I checked my chrome plugins also, there is nothing strange...

Comment: Is the initial content of the IFRAME empty?

Comment: @int32_t Yes it is, i fill it by clicking on the button